# Hide rows in a column with vanilla JavaScript according to text content

Tags: javascript

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Digitised</th>
    </tr>
</table
```

I'd like to have a button which, when clicked, hides or shows the rows which contain a 'Yes' (or a check, or a specific element) in the 'Digitised' column.

This is the JavaScript I've come up so far

```
      let table, tr, td, i, t;
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for(t=0; t<tds.length; t1++) {
                let td = tds[t][3];
                if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.indexOf('Yes') > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = 'none';
                  }
                }
            }
        }
```

This doesn't work. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: `let tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];` you're selecting a specific `<td>` element; `for(t=0; t<tds.length; t++) ` is expecting multiple `<td>` elements. What are you intending to do here?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to select the specific cell of the fourth column of that row (the 'Digitised' one).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica PS: if I take the [3] out then the code runs and doesn't hide the rows anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong id in your Javascript, the table id is "mytable" (in lower case) but your js code is trying to find "myTable" which is camel case,

Anyways here is a sample of code that do what you need:

```js
var areRowsDisplayed = true

function toggleRows() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable > tbody > tr')
  Array.prototype.slice.call(rows).forEach(row => {
    let dataField = row.querySelectorAll('td')[3]
    if(dataField.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
      row.style.display = !areRowsDisplayed ? '': 'none'
    }
  })
  areRowsDisplayed = !areRowsDisplayed
}

document.querySelector('#toggleRows').addEventListener('click',e => toggleRows())
```

```html
<button id='toggleRows'>Hide/Show</button>
<table id="mytable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Digitised</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Pin Pon</td>
        <td>The new song</td>
        <td>1991</td>
        <td>No</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cloudies</td>
        <td>Fly with me</td>
        <td>1986</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This basically has a button that run a javascript function, and within that function we loop into each table row and hide/show the rows that meet certain criteria

I have added a global variable to check what is the current status (if the rows are hidden already) only for this sample purposes, you must be storing that in some context depending on the framework you are using